# unique percentile even for same value in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, series, percentile

I am looking to obtain unique percentiles even for same value in Python

For example, the following case is giving the output as expected.

Case 1

```
import pandas as pd
s1 = pd.Series([1,2,3,4])
s1.rank(pct=True)
```

Case 1 Output - `[0.25, 0.5, 0.75, 1]`

I expect the output to be same even when the input series is `[2, 2, 2, 4]`. However, here the output is [`0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 1]`.  I don't mind either one of the outputs.

```
[0.25, 0.5, 0.75, 1]    
[0.5, 0.25, 0.75, 1]
[0.25, 0.75, 0.5, 1]
```

Please let me know if there is a way to achieve that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rank has a parameter `method` which defaults to 'average' which gives you the results are you are seeing.  Let's change that to `'first'`.

```
s1 = pd.Series([2,2,2,4])
s1.rank(pct=True,method='first')
```

Output:

```
0    0.25
1    0.50
2    0.75
3    1.00
dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no simple function to do this.  Although I understand what you want to do, this is *not* a percentile score.  In fact, what you've shown here is a percentage rank, which is *not* the same as percentile.

To get the functionality you want, I believe that you'll have to group and compute the values yourself.